# startActivity not working on nested method call

Tags: android

I've had a look around but can't find an answer to this (probably really simple) problem of using intents to start different activities.

I'm trying to enable a button to start another activity when it's clicked.

Why does this work:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Act2);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.timsworth.ACTIVITY2"));
        }
    });
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Act2);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startAct();
        }
    });
}

public void startAct() {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.timsworth.ACTIVITY2"));
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

it is out of `onCreate()` method so you should mention `Context` explicitly, in your second code write it like this,

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),"com.timsworth.ACTIVITY2"));
```

Comment: i think "com.timsworth.ACTIVITY2" is wrong in your case ! because it can only be used with single parameter of Intent(String action)

Comment: i just added getAppplicationContext(), the rest is what the question owner's wrote :)

Comment: but these becomes two parameters ? and string is only allowed with single parameter of Intent()

Comment: two parameters? startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.timsworth.ACTIVITY2.class));

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.timsworth.ACTIVITY2.class)); doesn't work because com.timsworth.ACTIVITY2 isn't a valid classpath.  I've changed it to startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class)); and it still doesn't work.

Comment: My manifest entry for the activity is as follows:

<activity 
         android:name=".Activity2"
         android:label="Activity 2" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.timsworth.ACTIVITY2" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public void startAct() {
    startActivity(new Intent(yourCurrentActivity.this,com.timsworth.ACTIVITY2.class));
}
```

instead